How do I store text data in an account
I am trying to store small amount of metadata in an account but it always throws validation error. Do I need to create a custom program because of that? I am new to web3 kinds of stuff.
const secret_key = new Uint8Array(JSON.parse(process.env.SOLANA_SECRET_KEY))
const keypair = solana.Keypair.fromSecretKey(secret_key)
const connection = new solana.Connection(solana.clusterApiUrl('devnet'))


const data = Buffer.from("project_id: 1, status: 'something something', timestamp: 'sdfdsfsdfsfsdfsdfsd'", 'utf8');
const holder = solana.Keypair.generate();
const required_balance = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(data.length);

const create_account_transaction = new solana.Transaction()

create_account_transaction.add(solana.SystemProgram.createAccount({
    fromPubkey: keypair.publicKey,
    newAccountPubkey: holder.publicKey,
    lamports: required_balance,
    space: data.length,
    programId: solana.SystemProgram.programId,
}))

const sig1 = await solana.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, create_account_transaction, [keypair, holder])

const write_data_transaction = new solana.Transaction()
write_data_transaction.add(
    new solana.TransactionInstruction({
        keys: [{ pubkey: holder.publicKey, isSigner: false, isWritable: true }],
        programId: solana.SystemProgram.programId,
        data,
    })
);

try {
    await solana.sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, write_data_transaction, [keypair])
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}


If you want to write data to an account, you need to use some other program. In this case, you're assigning the account to the system program, but the account already belongs to the system program. After that, you're sending the data to the system program, but the system program doesn't know how to interpret that instruction data.
You might want to read up on program fundamentals: https://solana.com/docs/intro/quick-start
